# jquery plugin options bug

Tags: javascript, plugins, d3.js

I've developed this jquery plugin. I have noticed an issue though - that when I create multiple instances of this pie chart - with different parameters - like size - the options are overriden globally. How do I avoid this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1319/

```
            init : function(options) {
                var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, options["data"]);

                methods.el = this;          
                methods.setup(clone, options["width"], options["height"]);
            },
            setup: function(dataset, w, h){             

                this.width = w;
                this.height = h;
                this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;

                this.color = d3.scale.category20();

                this.pie = d3.layout.pie()
                    .sort(null);

                this.arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .innerRadius(this.radius - 100)
                    .outerRadius(this.radius - 50);

                this.svg = d3.select(methods.el["selector"]).append("svg")
                    .attr("width", this.width)
                    .attr("height", this.height)
                    .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "piechart")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")");                

                //this.update(dataset[0].segments); 
            },
```

Comment: Similar issue for these http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/160/

Comment: and this http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/159/

Comment: Really need help with this - how do I set parameters as private per object? I've read one way is to set a data attribute on the object - that stores the parameters.

Comment: I've fixed the arc chart - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/163/ and the pie chart now - http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1321/ - by just passing back the radius and inner radius into the tween functions

Comment: Fixed this concentric chart - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/165/